# Good set with $n$ elements must have element $\ge {2\over n}\binom{n}{n\over2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let $n$ be even. A set $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ consisting of positive integer s is *good* if for every two different disjoint subsets $S$, $T \subseteq [n]$ of the same cardinality we have$$\sum_{i \in S} a_i \neq \sum_{i \in T} a_i.$$How do I see that any good set $A$ with $n$ elements must necessarily contain an element that is greater or equal than$${2\over n}\binom{n}{n\over2}?$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that every element of $A$ is less than $\frac2n\binom{n}{n/2}$. If $S\subseteq A$, and $|S|=\frac{n}2$, then $\sum S<\binom{n}{n/2}$. Thus, there must be $S_0,S_1\subseteq A$ such that $S_0\ne S_1$, $|S_0|=|S_1|=\frac{n}2$, and $\sum S_0=\sum S_1$. Show that $S_0\setminus S_1$ and $S_1\setminus S_0$ are disjoint subsets of $A$ with the same sum.